# What is Xcode pbxstrings file for?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an Xcode project and needed to change the name of the product it builds.  I went through the project files with a fine-toothed comb and thought I had made every change possible.  The last step was to grep all files in the project folder for occurrences of the old name.  It comes up clean.

But after a build grep finds a file which contains several occurrences of the old name.  It is in a location like:
  MyProjectFolder/build/MyProject.build/MyProject.pbxindex/strings.pbxstrings/strings

I can't imagine where it is getting the old name from.  Also, I have no idea what this file is used for.  But I am concerned that apparently I haven't purged the old name everywhere.

Can anyone tell me what the ...pbxstrings/strings file is for and how it gets built?  If I understand that I can probably track down the last remnants of the old name and purge them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That MyProject.pbxindex is just there for CodeSense. :) Close Xcode and delete the MyProject.pbxindex directory (make a copy if you are skeptical) and then reopen Xcode. It will rebuild it.

If you wanted to, you could do this from the command line:

xcodeindex -project /path/to/your/project clean build

I would just do the first one though.

Comment: I could not figure out what the pbxindex was used for until I read this answer.  All the google results were dead ends.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the "Rebuild CodeSense Index" button in the project inspector's General pane is probably easier than issuing command-line commands that do the same thing.

The indexer doesn't purge index entries for deleted entries immediately, but that will have no effect on your build.