# What does the error File type mismatch (~) mean?

Tags: cocoa, xcode

After upgrading to a newer version of Xcode, when I build my project I get and error:

File type mismatch (~), OutputModelPrefs.nib.

I have tried Googling and the Apple Developer Forum but I can't find out exactly what the problem is. Can anyone shed any light on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode stores file type information in `foo.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`. Maybe you should open that file in a text editor and see if there's anything conspicuous. Look for `lastKnownFileType =`. If that doesn't help, maybe recreating the project will.

BTW: is that really a . nib file, not a .xib file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly this means, I got it in a slightly different place.  Mine was complaining about a .pbxindex file with the same error message.  In my case, I deleted the .pbxindex and rebuilt.  After that the file was regenerated an all was fine.  More info on my error here: [What is Xcode pbxstrings file for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664947/what-is-xcode-pbxstrings-file-for)